# drop down value should change to selected option and not default- angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a select drop down. I have to show " select" as the default value. After selection an option, the value shown should be selected value.

```
  <select  #selectedPlanet
  (change)='onOptionsSelected(selectedPlanet.value)'>
    <option selected hidden>Select</option>

    <option *ngFor='let planet of planetsList' [value]="planet.name">{{planet.name}}</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

But now what happens is that, it shows "select" as default. But on selecting an option, the changed option changes to "select" in UI.Could anyone please help me

Comment: please include code snippet for `onOptionsSelected`

Answer (score 0):

```
<select #selectedPlanet (change)='onOptionsSelected($event.target.value)'>
                                    <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
                                    <option *ngFor="let planet of planetsList let i=index" value="{{planet.name}}">{{planet.name}}</option>
                                
                                </select>
```